# Optional fields in COBOL DB2

Tags: sql, db2, cobol, sql-like

I'm trying to write a SQL statement in COBOL DB2 which accepts a number of optional fields.

So far I've managed to make a VALID-FROM-DATE and VALID-TO-DATE and SYSTEM-ID optional by using the following code.

```
MOVE A-CURRENT-TIMESTAMP(1:10)
  TO A-VALID-FROM-DATE        
MOVE A-CURRENT-TIMESTAMP(1:10)
  TO A-VALID-TO-DATE          

MOVE 0               
  TO A-SYSTEM-ID-FROM
MOVE 999             
  TO A-SYSTEM-ID-TO
```

But now I want to make a fourth field optional and its a char field.

I've tried the following - it works in my SQL-Wizard but not when I run the program:

```
MOVE '%'    
  TO A-NAME
```

In the following DB2 SQL statement:

```
 SELECT                                      
       COALESCE(NAME,' ')                   
      ,SYSTEM_ID                             
      ,COALESCE(VALUE_DATE,'0001-01-01')     
 FROM TABLE                                
WHERE                                        
      NAME          LIKE :A-NAME            
  AND SYSTEM_ID  BETWEEN :A-SYSTEM-ID-FROM   
                     AND :A-SYSTEM-ID-TO     
  AND VALUE_DATE BETWEEN :A-VALID-FROM-DATE  
                     AND :A-VALID-TO-DATE    
 ORDER BY VALUE_DATE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was rather simple.
Instead of

```
MOVE '%'    
  TO A-NAME
```

I changed it to

```
MOVE '%%%%%%%'    
  TO A-NAME
```

as A-NAME is a X(7) field.

Comment: A side note, you can use "MOVE ALL '%' TO A-NAME" to accomplish the same thing in the case where the source field is a literal.

Comment: Yes, using ALL '%' will get the compiler to count the required number of %-signs, so always a more accurate way when using a literal.